# Fetch Data From DB and Display It in a Viewpager In A recyclerview

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager

Before marking as duplicate et al, viewpager from recyclerview is kind of triccky. The code is able to retrieve data from db and display it in a recyclerview with cardview. I want to be able to scroll the images in the viewpager while in the recyclerview as shown in the wireframe below, the dots represent number of images retrieved from DB which should be swipeeable right or left. Imageview seems not to be swipeable.

[image]

IMAGE ADAPTER.JAVA

```
public class ImageAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ImageAdapter.ViewHolder> {
        List<ImageList>imageLists;
        Context context;

public ImageAdapter(List<ImageList> imageLists, Context context) {
        this.imageLists = imageLists;
        this.context = context;
        }

@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.image_list,parent,false);
        return new ViewHolder(v);
        }

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        ImageList imageList = imageLists.get(position);
        holder.tvname.setText(imageList.getName());
        holder.tv2name.setText(imageList.getName2());


    String picture = imageList.getImageurl();
    String picture2 = imageList.getImage2url();
    String picture3 = imageList.getImage3url();

    String[] imageUrls = {picture, picture2, picture3};

        Picasso.get()
        .load(picture)
        .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)
        .error(R.drawable.error)
        .resize(0, 200)
        .into(holder.img);
        }

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
        return imageLists.size();
        }

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    private TextView tvname, tv2name;
    private ImageView img;
    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        img=(ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_view);
        tvname=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_name);
        tvname=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_name2);
    }
}
}
```

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center">

       <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
           app:cardElevation="3dp"
           app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
           android:padding="2dp"
           android:layout_margin="5dp">

           <ImageView
               android:id="@+id/image_view"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="200dp"
               android:contentDescription="ServerImg"
               android:scaleType="fitXY" />
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    <TextView
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:id="@+id/txt_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:id="@+id/txt_name2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You need an adapter for the root recyclerView, AND you need a viewPager with its own adapter for each group of swipable pictures. Each item of the root recyclerView will have it's own ViewPager and adapter for the ViewPager.

Comment: Thanks @DevJZ. . How is that achieavable?.